# Simple code to get java.lang.reflect.Type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

[GSON](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html)'s toJson function takes a type argument which checks the [Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) when reflecting the object. This is useful for reflecting objects into a collection.

However, the only way I can find to obtain the Type is through an ugly set of coding contortions:

```
//used for reflection only
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final List<MyObject> EMPTY_MY_OBJECT = null;
private static final Type MY_OBJECT_TYPE;

static {
    try {
        MY_OBJECT_TYPE = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("EMPTY_MY_OBJECT").getGenericType();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }   
}

private List<MyObject> readFromDisk() {

    try {
        String string = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(JSON_FILE_NAME), null);
        return new Gson().fromJson(string, MY_OBJECT_TYPE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way of initializing the Type without referencing internal class variables? The pseudocode would looks something like this:

```
private static final Type MY_OBJECT_TYPE = TypeUtils.generate(List.class, MyObject.class);
```

Comment: Have you tried writing your method with the interface you're looking at and run into a problem?

Comment: @Chris Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @patstuart the javadoc for `toJson` looks like they might answer your question. `Type typeOfSrc = new TypeToken<List<MyObject>>(){}.getType();`

Comment: @patstuart I'm referring to your pseudocode - `private static final Type MY_OBJECT_TYPE = TypeUtils.generate(List.class, MyObject.class);` - have you tried writing your own version of `TypeUtils.generate` to implement this proposed interface?

Comment: Actually in 2019 there is such a thing that is almost exactly what you expressed in the pseudocode:

`org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.TypeUtils.parameterize(...)`

See: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/TypeUtils.html#parameterize-java.lang.Class-java.lang.reflect.Type...-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Javadoc for [`toJson`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.reflect.Type)) looks to answer your question

> typeOfSrc - The specific genericized type of src. You can obtain this type by using the TypeToken class. For example, to get the type for Collection, you should use:

```
Type typeOfSrc = new TypeToken<Collection<Foo>>(){}.getType();
```

So in your instance.

```
private static final Type MY_OBJECT_TYPE = new TypeToken<List<MyObject>>(){}.getType();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to do like this:

```
 private static final Type MY_OBJECT_TYPE = TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, MyObject.class).getType();
```